# Negative correlation with .000 p value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation

How do we interpret this result? 
Also, is a p value of .000 an error?

The hypothesis should be tested with a .05 level of significance.

[image]

Comment: Please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=p-value+0.000 for more answers to this question.  For more about the interpretation of p-values see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/p-value?sort=votes.

Comment: This is SPSS? Try double click the table, and then click on the p-value cell, you should see the number expressed in scientific notation.